# ¿Es necesario agregar la etiqueta de un lenguaje cuando solo se etiqueta un framework o librería?

Tags: soporte

Espero ser más claro aquí ya que no supe como poner un título más preciso (si se les ocurre alguno no duden en editar mi pregunta)

Últimamente he visto muchas preguntas en las que solo se etiqueta el *framework*, *librería*, *plugin*, etc... pero no el lenguaje de este ¿esto se sobreentiende de por si?

Es decir, hay preguntas acerca de [jquery](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery),[extjs](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/extjs),[reactjs](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs),[angularjs](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs),etc... **que no poseen la etiqueta propia de su lenguaje**, el cual en estos casos sería [javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), personalmente yo navego por el sitio buscando preguntas que responder acerca de esta última etiqueta y sus afines, y me he encontrado con que he ***perdido de vista*** muchas preguntas afines al no encontrar cierta etiqueta en las preguntas.

> ¿Es o **no** es necesario agregar la etiqueta del lenguaje propio de una librería o framework?

Pregunto porque esto pasa también con etiquetas como [java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), entre otras

Comment: depende de la pregunta, una pregunta sobre reactjs puede no ser una pregunta sobre javascript. Ej, una pregunta que trata sobre el ciclo de vida de un componente no necesita estar etiquetada como javascript ya que no trata sobre aspectos del lenguaje en si.

Comment: Depende también del lenguaje. En el caso de Java, al menos, yo sí lo recomiendo porque la etiqueta Java recibe más atención que las etiquetas basadas en frameworks.

Answer (score 4):

Creo que pasa con todos los lenguajes, ¿cierto? Yo me acabo de quejar en [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36467036#36467036) de eso mismo.

Usar todas las etiquetas relevantes tiene muchas ventajas:

- aumenta la visibilidad de tu pregunta,
- facilita las búsquedas,
- te permite establecer etiquetas favoritas
- u ocultar las que no deseas ver,
- hay un canal de RSS para cada etiqueta
- hay poderosos filtros de búsqueda, (no me acuerdo del enlace, pero es un sitio de SE).

El problema es que muchos de nosotros desconocemos todas estas ventajas, tal vez solo nos interesa que nos resuelvan un problema inmediato, o simplemente no van a participar en la comunidad ni a usar sus herramientas.

No creo que pueda establecerse una política que automáticamente tenga como consecuencia que *todos* usen **siempre** todas las etiquetas relevantes. Por muy **necesario** que sea.

Corresponde a cada persona, de forma individual y por decisión propia, promover el uso correcto de las etiquetas, por ejemplo, dando a conocer las ventajas.

En resumen, usar correctamente las etiquetas, mas que necesario, es deseable, es una buena práctica, es recomendable, es más efectivo... pero requiere de *evangelizadores*.

Así que cada que puedas, recuerda promover las etiquetas. O simplemente edita la pregunta y agrégala. No siempre te lo van a agradecer, pero siempre va a servir.